# Calling a redux action with previously passed parameters as arguments

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Is there a way to call a redux action with previously passed parameters in the action instead of manually sending the parameters.

```
Let's say the first action receives a payload data as arguments
Action1(arg1,arg2)

The second action call I make should fetch previous payload data
 as arguments
 Action2(//fetch previously called action parameters here which is arg1, arg2)
```

Comment: There's not enough information to understand what you're trying to do here. Can you please expand this with a much more detailed explanation?

Comment: @markerikson edited